# Why Datagrid in WPF can sort when all data in that column is the same?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question. When I try to make a custom sorting data for my datagrid. I found a problem is: Sorting is work when all data on each cell of that column is the same.

More detail: I have a list include (id, name) id is unique, but all name = "＊ ＊". This symbol is japanese.

I had try to make a class inherit Icomparer and override Comparer() method with

```
CompareInfo compInfo = new CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo("ja-JP");
return compInfo.Compare(str1,str2, CompareOption.StringSort) * mode;
```

Mode is direction of sort

I had to try all of CompareOption. Include using Strings.StrComp() of VB but it still returns a different result when sort. My expect is when all of the value of that column is the same, index of item is my datagrid will not change.

Thanks, sorry my bad english!

Comment: Please add some sample data, your implementation of `IComparer` and your expected results.

Comment: @RyanWilson Compare method of IComparer always return 0, but datagrid still sorted? I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the sort order is indeterminate when the names are the same. Sort also by `id` when the names are equal.

```
CompareInfo compInfo = new CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo("ja-JP");
int result = compInfo.Compare(str1, str2, CompareOption.StringSort);
if (result == 0) { // str1 and str2 are equal.
    result = compInfo.Compare(id1, id2);
}
return result * mode;
```

Assuming the `id` is a string. If the ids are `int`, then compare

```
if (result == 0) { // str1 and str2 are equal.
    result = id1.CompareTo(id2);
}
```

Note: `CompareInfo.Compare` and `Int32.CompareTo` return -1 if the first value is smaller than the second, +1 the first is lager than the second and otherwise, when both values are equal, 0.

Comment: hmm, I just relize that result is never != 0, but datagrid still sorted, just sorted the first time I clicked on the header column, the next time is not, do you know why?

Comment: Probably the first time you are sorting the data source with your comparer. But the datagrid does not know anything about your comparer and is not using it when you click on a header. Search for [WPF datagrid custom sort](https://www.google.com/search?q=WPF+datagrid+custom+sort).